# ColdFusion queryExecute parameters object?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11, cfquery, cfqueryparam

I started using `cfscript` in my projects recently. While working with `cfscript` I used `queryExecute()` function to run queries. In few situations there was more than one query in the same function. These queries shared some of the same parameters. I was wondering if I can have one structure that will hold all parameters for all queries. This is what I tried:

```
local.qryParams = structNew();
structAppend(qryParams, {rec_id = {cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric", value="#arguments.rec_id#"}});
structAppend(qryParams, {position = "#application.position#"});
structAppend(qryParams, {user_id = "#client.userid#"});
structAppend(qryParams, {title = {cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar", value="#arguments.title#", maxlength: 50}});
structAppend(qryParams, {description = {cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar", value="#arguments.description#", maxlength: 1000}});
```

Then I have two variables with SQL:

```
local.insertSQL = "
    INSERT INTO notes(rec_id, title, description, user_id, last_update) 
    VALUES (:rec_id, :title, :description, :user_id, getDate())
";
local.updateSQL = "
    UPDATE profile
    SET last_update = getDate(),
        user_id = :user_id
    WHERE rec_id = :rec_id
        AND position = :position
";
```

Then on the very end I have two execute functions:

```
queryExecute(insertSQL, qryParams , {datasource="#application.datasource#", result: "insertResult"});
queryExecute(updateSQL, qryParams , {datasource="#application.datasource#", result: "updateResult"});
```

Both functions executed successfully and record was inserted/updated. My questions are:

- Is this a good approach to store all query parameters in one structure?
- Is there any potential problem or security issue doing it that way?
- Any suggestions/comments?

Thank you!

Comment: *In few situations there was more than one query in the same function* If any of the queries are used multiple times, like 'update profile', I'd move those queries to a separate function.

Comment: @Ageax Is there any benefit moving that query to a separate function other than redundancy effect. Thank you.

Comment: The primarily benefit is eliminating redundant code. There's a minor o/h in calling additional methods, but IMO that's outweighed by the gains in clarity and eliminating duplication. Another option is using stored procedures. The advantage of procs is a) they're capable of more complex logic b) can return multiple results (cfquery's can't) c) only require a single trip to the db. In fairness, you can also do "c)" with a cfquery - but that's not what cfquery's designed for.

Comment: I would highly recommend stored procedures for more than simple sql. Also, don't forget that you don't really want to make multiple connections to your database if you can help it. If you can send the data to a sproc rather than running multiple CF functions, that would be much nicer to your network and database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of an open ended question, but here goes

**Q1:** Is this a good approach to store all query parameters in one structure?
**A1:** Yes, but you may want to consider using entities if you like this.

**Q2:** Is there any potential problem or security issue doing it that way?
**A2:** None that I know of

**Q3:** Any suggestions/comments?
**A3:**

1. If your datasource is in `application.cfc`, you don't need to explicity state it.
2. You are getting the result the hard way. Consider `myResult=QueryExecute(...)`
3. You can build the struct in one shot. You don't need all these `structAppend()`s. `structNew()` is way too much typing. Consider `{}`.
4. `user_id = "#client.userid#"` is way too much typing... Just `user_id = client.userid` is enough.
5. You changed styles of building structs `{cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar", value="#arguments.title#", maxlength: 50}`. IMHO, use `:` instead of `=`

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Two other comments. Don't forget to 1) local scope any `result` variables to avoid threading issues 2) wrap multiple, related queries, in a transaction.